# Contact form file attachment not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a file attachment in my contact form as you can see here:
http://www.cuylas.com/empleo/

I'm getting all of the fields but the file. Do you know where is the problem?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the code of my form page https://pastebin.com/2bupCGTx

Comment: did you do any code to send file in email???

Comment: The only code I have is the one I attached located at /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/empleo.phtml

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**1. Modify your contact form template**

You need to modify the contact form template file:

app/design/frontend/[yourinterface]/[yourtheme]/template/contacts/form.phtml:

a) Add enctype=”multipart/form-data” in  element as:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

b) Add file upload field below ‘Comment’ field (or anywhere you want) as:

```
<li>
    <label for="attachment"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Attachment') ?></label>
    <div>
        <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" value="2000000" />
        <input name="attachment" id="attachment" type="file" />
    </div>
</li>
```

**2. Create controller class for processing file upload**

Next step override `Mage_Contacts_IndexController`

a) Add xml override code in your module’s config.xml as:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <contacts>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <magefreak_customcontact before="Mage_Contacts">MageFreak_Customcontact</magefreak_customcontact>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </contacts>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

b) Create your custom controller

Create controller file in your module dir as:

```
app/code/local/MageFreak/Customcontact/controllers/IndexController.php
```

Copy this following code in it

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php';
class MageFreak_Contactspro_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                /**************************************************************/
                $fileName = '';
                if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != '') {
                    try {
                        $fileName       = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $fileName       = preg_replace('/\s+', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . '.' . $fileExt;

                        $uploader       = new Varien_File_Uploader('attachment');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'contacts';
                        if(!is_dir($path)){
                            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                        }
                        $uploader->save($path . DS, $fileName );

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
                /**************************************************************/

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */

                /**************************************************************/
                //sending file as attachment
                $attachmentFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS . 'contacts' . DS . $fileName;
                if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
                    $fileContents = file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath);
                    $attachment   = $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents);
                    $attachment->filename = $fileName;
                }
                /**************************************************************/

                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 2 a) where can I find the file?

Comment: Ok so, step 2 a) I did it on app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml

Then I followed the rest of steps, and a File Attachment appeared on my contact form. But I don't want it to appear there, I have 2 different contact forms, one standard (the one that got modified now, http://www.cuylas.com/contacto/), and one so people can send their CV (http://www.cuylas.com/empleo/). The second one is the one I want it to work. I already have the file attachment there, but it doesn't attach it on mail, other variables are sending ok.

Comment: @ Èric H. First and foremost thing you should remember that not to modify core files. In this case you have to create module  app/code/local/MageFreak/Customcontact/etc/config.xml. And now coming to your issue you have to create custom contact form for (cuylas.com/empleo).  In that Contact form you have to add Step1. Refer this link http://ignaciogondra.com/2015/08/24/how-to-create-a-custom-contact-form-in-magento/ to create custom contact form.